# Automorphisms of a field extension (proof verification)

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

I am asked to compute the automorphisms of the field extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})/\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$.

I know that $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2}):\mathbb{Q}]=4$ since 
$$
\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})=\{a+b\sqrt[4]{2}+c\sqrt[4]{4}+d\sqrt[4]{8}\,\mid\,a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{Q}\}.
$$
We also know that $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}):\mathbb{Q}]=2$ so by the Tower Law we have $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2}):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})]=2.$ Indeed, given $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{Q}$ we have
\begin{align*}
a+b\sqrt[4]{2}+c\sqrt[4]{4}+d\sqrt[4]{8}&=a+c\sqrt[4]{4}+b\sqrt[4]{2}+d\sqrt[4]{8}\\
&=(a+c\sqrt{2})+(b+d\sqrt{2})\sqrt[4]{2}.
\end{align*}

So it seems to me that there are exactly two automorphisms for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})/\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$: the identity and $\sigma((a+c\sqrt{2})+(b+d\sqrt{2})\sqrt[4]{2})=(a+c\sqrt{2})-(b+d\sqrt{2})\sqrt[4]{2}.$

Does this seem reasonable or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT:** The minimal polynomial of $\sqrt[4]{2}$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ is $p(x)=x^2-\sqrt{2}$ so any automorphism must map roots of $p(x)$ to roots of $p(x)$. The roots of this polynomial are $\sqrt[4]{2}$ and $-\sqrt[4]{2}$ so, what are the possibilities?

Comment: Right. $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})$ is a quadratic extension of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$, so there are only two choices. The problem asked me to compute the automorphisms directly, which prompted me to approach it the way I did. Thanks for the verification and for another way to look at it.